# how to insert multiple rows values into databse using mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one table usercontacts. columns are

```
ContactType 
ContactNumber
```

in my view.cshtml page i am using dropdownlist for select  contacttype(Emial,phno,mbno) and textbox for contactnumber

```
Email         Abc@abc.com
phno          1234567890
mbno          1234567890
```

how to insert at a time these three values into database.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need start [MVC.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc) and for work with data you need start with [entity framework](http://learnentityframework.com/learnentityframework/) 
:see [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/models-%28data%29).